# Best way to define multiple list variables inside class in Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have created a script that stores and edits meta-data in a system. I am now cleaning up my code by defining a class and methods, previously I only used separate functions.

In the script I am storing old and new values of certain types of metadata in lists, which I print out after the script has completed its run. I have defined multiple lists (16 to be exact), which I realized is quite a lot when passing them through a method. I was wondering what is the most pythonic way to approach this.

These are the following list variables that i define in the beginning. In the function/method I append values to them. In the end I print the stored valued out as a report.

```python
split_name = []
split_name_new = []
name = []
name_new = []
meta = []
meta_new = []
series = []
series_new = []
product = []
owner = []
desc = []
desc_new = []
keywords = []
keywords_new = []
no_edit_page =[]
no_edit_page_name = []
```

In a class i figured it will look something like (if I define all the list separately)

```python
class Metadata_editor():
    def __init__(self,url):

        self.split_name = [] 
        self.split_name_new = []
        self.name = []
        self.name_new = []
        self.meta = []
        self.meta_new = []
        self.series = []
        self.series_new = []
        self.product = []
        self.owner = []
        self.desc = []
        self.desc_new = []
        self.keywords = []
        self.keywords_new = []
        self.no_edit_page =[]
        self.no_edit_page_name = []

        #Ugly solution because the method gets crowded by all the variables passed through
        def data_edit(self, split_name, split_name_new, name, name_new,.. etc):
            #Not the whole method, but just to give some idea..
            #Selenium function that locates meta
            md = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='metadata-name']") 
            meta_data = md.get_attribute("value")
            #replace_words translate the word using a dictionary object
            meta_data_new = replace_words(meta_data,c) 
            meta.append(meta_data)
            meta_new.append(meta_data_new)
```

The solution above I realized would not be ideal.

I found an alternative way that I could use, which is I define a list of lists. The solution would then look something like this (see below). However 'data_list[10]' is not as self-explanatory as for say 'owner'. My question is, is this the 'best' way to solve this, or do you have any other suggestions? I don't really have anything against this solution, but was wondering if there is a more 'pythonic' way to approach this.

```python
class Metadata_editor():
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.data_list=[[] for _ in range(16)] #Creates a list, that contains 16 lists

    # More eloquent solution, as only one variable is passed through. However finding 
    # the right data from data_list is perhaps not as easy before 
    def data_edit(self, data_list): 

        md = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='metadata-name']")
        meta_data = md.get_attribute("value")
        meta_data_new = replace_words(meta_data,c)
        data_list[5].append(meta_data)
        data_list[6].append(meta_data_new)
```

Comment: Why would you need to pass them as they are part of self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize multiple lists as below:

```
class Metadata_editor():
    def __init__(self,list_names):
        [setattr(self,name,[]) for name in list_names]
```

```
me = Metadata_editor(['split_name','split_name_new']) # initialize two lists
me.split_name.append(5) # add value to a list
print(me.split_name, me.split_name_new)
```

**>>[5], [ ]**

---

Once set as part of the class via `self.list_name`, the list(s) can be accessed globally within the class - no longer requiring to be 'passed in'. To initialize lists to specific values, you can do:

```
def __init__(self,list_names,list_values):
    [setattr(self,name,value) for name,value in zip(list_names,list_values)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store it as a dictionary. That would have the advantage of being able to reference the keys by name rather than having to remember the indexes.

```
class Metadata_editor():
    def __init__(self, url):
       keys = [
            'split_name', 'split_name_new', 'name', 'name_new' 'meta', 'meta_new',
            'series', 'series_new', 'product', 'owner', 'desc', 'desc_new',
            'keywords', 'keywords_new', 'no_edit_page', 'no_edit_page_name',
        ]
        self.data_dict = dict((x, []) for x in keys)

    def data_edit(self):
        md = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='metadata-name']")
        meta_data = md.get_attribute("value")
        meta_data_new = replace_words(meta_data,c)
        self.data_dict['meta'].append(meta_data)
        self.data_dict['meta_new'].append(meta_data_new)
```

A few extra points to note:

- class names generally follow the UpperCaseCamelCase convention. So `Metadata_editor` would more conventionally be written as `MetadataEditor`
- Using `self` sets an attribute on the class, it can be accessed in the class using `self` and the attribute does not need to be passed into the method. *I have shown this in the example above, accessing `self.data_dict` in the `data_edit` method*.
- You can also use `setattr` to set attributes to the class as shown in some of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setattr`:

```
...
def __init__(self, url):
    names = '''split_name split_name_new name
        name_new meta meta_new series series_new
        product owner desc desc_new keywords
        keywords_new no_edit_page
        no_edit_page_name'''.split()
    for name in names:
        setattr(self, name, [])
...
```